# How can I change a value by another value using some criteria in R?

Tags: r

Hi I have this data frame `G <- data.frame(Value = c(20,100,2001))` and I want to apply this rule:

```
if Value[i] < 1000
```

so

```
Value[i]*100
```

My expective data frame is

```
  Value
1  2000
2 10000
3  2001
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `ifelse(G$Value < 1000, G$Value * 100, G$Value)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use some logical subsetting of the data.frame to only change those values that fit your criteria:
`G[G$Value < 1000, "Value"] <- G[G$Value < 1000, "Value"]*100`